# Mips: store a variable in another variable

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to translate a C program into MIPS assembly code

In my C code I have a line like this:

```
int base;
int count;

count = base;
```

In MIPS, how would I store the value of base inside of count? The only instructions I see for loading and storing are `lw` and `sw` and their prototypes only go from a register source -> ram destination or a ram source -> register destination.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I was hoping that this could be done in a single instruction, something like

`move base acc`

but apparently that is impossible (at least I found no example of an instruction similar to that), I opted for this:

```
lw $t0, base   //load base into $t0
sw $t0, count  //store the value of $t0 in count
```

If there is a one-line instruction to do this that would be better if anyone knows one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MIPS doesn't support direct memory-to-memory moves. (Neither do most common CPUs, actually -- even x86 doesn't.) You'll need to use `lw`/`sw` to move data around.

Architecturally, this is because MIPS is designed to only perform a single memory access per cycle -- doing a memory-to-memory move would require two accesses (one read, one write), or stall the pipeline.

Comment: The values of `base` and `counter` aren't in registers, they are stored in the RAM. So when I do this I just get an error message.

Comment: Oh, if they aren't registers then it's different. Updating.

Comment: It'd be nice it they could optimize that instruction, even though it is one more line for `lw/sw` equivalent, I spent a good 1hr+ searching for the instruction.

Comment: Like I said, though, there's no way to do it in a single instruction on a classic MIPS-style architecture without pipeline stalls (or a double-ported memory).

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to do it in MIPS

```
la $t0, base     // load the address of "base"
la $t1, count    // load the address of "count"
lw $t2, 0($t0)   // load the data at location "base"
sw $t2, 0($t1)   // store that data at location "count"
```

It is not possible to do a memory to memory move in a single instruction.

Comment: You can actually do it in only 2 instructions: `lw $t0, base` then `sw $t0, count`

Comment: `lw $t0, base` is just MIPS assembler shorthand for `lui $at,%hi(base)` followed by `lw $t0,%lo(base)(at)`. The load then store sequence is still a total of 4 machine instructions.

Comment: but only two physical instructions.

Comment: No. My orignal comment was not well explained.  `lw $t0, base` expands to 2 instructions. `sw $t0,count` expands to 2 instructions.  This gives a total of 4 instructions for the sequence. Physical instructions and machine instructions and instructions are all the same thing on MIPS. Each one occupies a 32 bit word in the executable file and in memory.

Comment: Who can explain what does `0($t1)` mean?

Comment: @entithat it turns the value of `$t1` into a memory address. If `$t1` stores `0x00001b08` then `0($t0)` is like a "pointer" to the memory location addressed by `0x00001b08`