# Storing one variable value into another MIPs

Tags: assembly, load, mips, store

I'm trying to load my sum variable here $s1 into my largestSum variable $s0. I looked up a little on how to load variables into other variables like this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107093/mips-store-a-variable-in-another-variable) but it still doesn't work giving an error

> Error in mips1.asm line 45: Runtime exception at 0x0040008c: address out of range 0x00000000

Now I'm not really sure what is going on anymore. Is that not the right way to do that? Did I store these variables incorrectly from the start?

Answer (score 0):

I used the stack stored the sum in there and then stored the stack into the largestsum.

```
subi $t7, $t7, 1 #reset the sgt variable to 0
sw $s1, 4($sp) #Store the sum into the stack
lw $s0, 4($sp) #Store the sum into the largestSum
b innerLoop
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked is about variables stored in memory, not in registers.
You are holding your variables `sum` and `largestSum` in two registers (`$s1`, `$s0` respectively).

Just use `move $s0, $s1` to copy the contents of sum into largestSum.